# How to add double quotes in sublime build file?

Tags: c++, cmd, g++, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I want to compile my C++ program in sublime text 3 and run it in cmd.
For that, I created a new build system(Tools-->Build System).

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",
"shell": "true",
"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}" ,"&&","start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
        "shell": true
    }
] }
```

This executes:

`g++ file_location -o file_location && start cmd /k file_location`

What I want to implement is(so that it holds the screen after execution finishes, and should exit on pressing any key in cmd):

`g++ file_location -o file_location && start cmd /c "file_location && pause>nul"`

(i.e replace `k` with `c` and implement double quotes)

I have tried `\"`

Instead of passing `"` , it passes whole `\"` which produces error in cmd.

What should i do?

Comment: By inverted comma, do you mean *single quote*?  And double inverted commas as *double quotes*?

Comment: Yup............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i figured it out myself.
i should delete `[` and `]` , so that instead of an array, a single string is passed. Now, to use double quotes, write `\"` instead of `"`

Original:   `"cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}" ,"&&","start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"]`

Modified `"cmd": "g++ ${file} -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name} && start cmd /c /"$file_base_name &&pause/" "`